# Forking a child or threading?

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server, fork

I have a server-client system..where each clients mmap the file found on the server. As soon as a client updates the file, the server needs to notify the clients to update their file..i.e. they should unmap and mmap the file again.  I thought that a solution to this problem is to send a string "Update" to the client by using write() (in the server side)..and do an infinite while loop to continue waiting for such "Update" by using read() (in the client side).  However, this while loop should be in some sort of thread or child process.  Which is best? and any other suggestions please?  Much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the file is opened with MAP_SHARED the updates will be visible immediately. No need to unmap() and mmap(). You still need your "update" signal and probably shared mutex for synchronisation of access.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using sockets and the select statement. With a setup like this you can make event based programming

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your suggestion.  I have searched for using select() at the client side, however, I am still not clear on how to apply it in my scenario.  Would it be possible for you to explain further please?  Thank you for you assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The server could send a [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) which the clients would trap and act accordingly.

Just take care of what your signal handler will do (there are many functions that are not safe to call in the context of signal handling).

Also be aware of race conditions and careful to not lose signals.

Comment: So is it possible to send a signal..from the server to the client??..Aren't signals sent to only processes on same machine?

Comment: @user3770009, oops. Sorry. I thought your clients were on the same machine of the server (perhaps because of mmap()). Excuse me and ignore it.

Comment: Still, you could use the socket approach with SIGIO (instead of select).

Comment: Forget SIGIO as the handler should call select() to know from which filedescriptor it came.